# How to choose the correct table of Joomla database?

Tags: mysql, database, joomla

My Joomla website DB is

```
mysite_2
```

I have a table

```
mysite_2 »Table: TABLE 2
```

How should I access it?

```
$query->select($db->qn(array('*')))
      ->from($db->qn('**WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?**'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a space in the table name, then you should write:

```
$query->select($db->qn(array('*')))
  ->from($db->qn('`TABLE 2`'))
```

Generally, all the fields and the table names in MySQL must be encapsulated with backticks.

Comment: Please do not remove the backticks from the answer - they need to be there. It's not a mistake. Please read my answer in full before modifying it.